# Trying to install jssor slider module with drupal 7.36

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, jssor

I am trying to install jssor module in Drupal 7.36. This is what I have done so far:

1. Downloaded and installed the libraries module.
2. Downloaded [Jssor Slider Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jssor) (7.x-1.x-dev) and extracted to "jssor" folder in

> **sites/all/modules/**

3. Downloaded the [jssor slider](https://github.com/jssor/slider) (slider-master.zip), extracted and renamed the folder as 'jssor-slider' and placed it under

> **sites/all/libraries/**

4. Enabled Jssor Slider in drupal->modules

Now I get this error in Status Report:

> Error
>       JSSOR Library
>   The JSSOR Slider library. Download from wwww.jssor.com

How can I fix this? I am pretty sure the library is installed.

```
$info1 = libraries_info('jssor-slider'); var_dump($info1['version arguments']);
```

shows

```
array(4) { ["file"]=> string(11) "js/jssor.js" ["pattern"]=> string(30) "@[Js]ssor\s+([0-9a-zA-Z\.-]+)@" ["lines"]=> int(5) ["cols"]=> int(50) }
```

I would also appreciate any link where I can learn more about using jssor slider in drupal 7x. I have tried but couldn't find any.

Thank you.